# Reference Excel Workbook made by Worksheet.copy Method

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to copy worksheets into a new Workbooks using the `.Copy`[(MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) method and then save and email these newly created files out.

To do this I will need a reference to the newly created worksheet in my macro. I haven't found a way to do it directly with the copy and am hesitant to always look for `Book1.xlsx`.

Is there a way to grab the most recently opened workbook or easily compare before and after collections of workbooks?

Comment: The newly created book1 (or whatever Excel calls it) should become the `ActiveWorkBook`, which you can assign to a variable and then just use the variable name to refer back to it when you want to switch back and forth.

Comment: @JoeMalpass: That is a valid answer. Why not post it as an answer with a small code sample? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout ... I'm just feeling lazy today. Someone else can have the points :)

Comment: Now I feel guilty. Answer below. Hahaha.

Comment: @JoeMalpass: It's too late now. Don't you think ;)?

Comment: Maybe so, but I feel better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell the worksheet `Copy` method to place the sheet Before/After a sheet in another workbook. So create a new workbook and then copy your sheet to before the first sheet in the new workbook.

```
Dim newBook As Workbook

Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

Workbooks("source_book.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet_name").Copy Before:=newBook.Worksheets(1)
```

You've then got a valid workbook reference to the book that holds the copy of the sheet.

Comment: No need to create a new workbook. Worksheets.Copy without an argument will create the new workbook by default.

Comment: @Jim Becker but OP wants a reference to the new workbook and this is best method to get that

Answer (score 0):

Oh alright then.

```
Dim origBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
Set origBook = Workbooks.ActiveWorkBook

yourcode..yourcode..yourcode.Copy

Set newBook = Workbooks.ActiveWorkBook
```

Something like that.